# Find element at position sqrt(n) in linked list in one iteration

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

How to find the element at position sqrt(n) in linked list where n is the number of elements in linked list in one iteration? We don't know the size of the list before we start.

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem. Is it?

Comment: Do you know the size of the list before you iterate?

Comment: @MooingDuck No we don't know the size

Comment: What _exactly_ does "one iteration" mean here?  Is it ok if one iterator iterates completely and a second iterator only iterates partially? Or that each item can only be iterated from exactly once?  Are external data structures allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something similar to the [Tortoise and hare algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Floyd's_Tortoise_and_Hare) for detecting cycles in linked lists. Specifically, start at the beginning of the list with a fast pointer *FP* and a slow pointer *SP*. Then repeatedly,

- *SP* advances one step
- *FP* advances progressively more steps: 1, then 3, then 5, then 7...

The key is that 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + ... (*N* terms) is *N²*. Thus, after *N* repetitions, *SP* will be at position *N* while *FP* will be at position *N²*. Whenever *FP* reaches the end of the linked list, *SP* holds the answer.

Comment: That has more than one iteration

Comment: I rephrased "iteration" into "repeatedly" to clarify that  I don't use "iteration" with the same meaning as the OP. There is a loop here, there obviously has to be one, but the total number of elements visited is `L` (from `FP`) plus sqrt(`L`) (from `SP`), where `L` is the unknown length of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest Solution:

```
int sqrth(node* head)
{
    node* temp1=head;
    node* temp2=head;
    int k=1;
    while(1)
    {
        int l=k*k;
        int r=(k+1)*(k+1)-1;

        for(int i=l;temp1->next&&i<r;i++)// e.g. when k=2  range[4,7] return 
        temp1=temp1->next;

        if(!temp1->next)
        return temp2->data;

        temp2=temp2->next;
        temp1=temp1->next;

        k++;
    }
}
```